# Was Jessica Jones a private investigator in the comics as well?

Tags: marvel, comics, adaptation-comparison, jessica-jones

I've been watching the first season of Jessica Jones, I came to know she was a former superhero but now she's a private investigator.

Was she a superhero in comics or was she portrayed as a former superhero turned detective just like the series?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jessica Jones debuted in Alias #1, a series under Marvel's MAX imprint (for mature readers).  In that, she was indeed portrayed as a former superhero turned private detective from the get-go, there was no previously established continuity as a superhero.  In fact, one of the first scenes from the comic, and the character's life, was similar to an early scene in the series, where Jessica tosses a client through her window and follows up with "and then there's the matter of your bill."

[image]

(The original image contains an F-bomb, I believe, probably removed for preview purposes on SFW websites).

Her superheroing career was hinted at throughout the series, with things like photos on the wall and friendships with other heroes that revealed the shared backstory.  Issues #22 and #23 were flashback issues of her short career as Jewel, leading up to her domination by the Purple Man.  It is in these issues that we see for the first time any superheroing action by Jessica Jones as Jewel.

[image]